# Timeout exceeded for Mocha promises

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, truffle, oraclize

I have a async function that awaits a promise which resolves when it receives some 'data'. However, when I run the test, I get a `Error: Timeout of 300000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

Here is my code snippet, I am using this in truffle to test solidity contracts :

```
contract("Test", async (accounts) => {
  it("test description", async () => {
       
      let first = await getFirstEvent(oracle.LogResult({fromBlock:'latest'}));
      let second = await getFirstEvent(oracle.LogResult({fromBlock:'latest'}));
      Promise.all([first,second]);
      //some assertion code
      
  });
  
  const getFirstEvent = (_event) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      _event.once('data', resolve).once('error', reject)
    });
  }

});
```

Isn't the promise resolving ? I can see 'data' coming back in the callback because I am emitting the callback event in the solidity code I am testing.

Comment: Do you have `done()` after your assertions?

Comment: @J.F. I did put a done() after the assert but it threw an error saying that done can not be used with a promise. I read up and realised async functions return promises by default - didn't know that earlier. btw, in this case, I am also using multiple callbacks (using promises) in some tests (edited my question for this), and I have also used a Promise.all(callback1, callback2) but even then, I am getting timeouts. How do we set timeouts in promises ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue, so posting it here so that others can use the approach.

I created a Promise that times out after a duration we can set :

```
const timeoutPromise = new Promise((_, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {a
    reject(new Error('Request timed out'));
  }, 200000);
})
```

Then, I race the timeoutPromise with the Promise which is fetching data, like this for the case I posted :

```
Promise.race([getFirstEvent(oracle.LogResult({fromBlock:'latest'})), timeoutPromise]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there's a few things wrong here.

First of all, your function isn't returning anything i.e. it should be `return Promise.all([first, second]);`.

Secondly, if the goal of the promise.all is to execute the promises in parallel, then that's not what it's doing here because you already have `await` statements on those function calls above.  What you are looking for here would be:

```
return await Promise.all([
  getFirstEvent(oracle.LogResult({fromBlock:'latest'}),
  getFirstEvent(oracle.LogResult({fromBlock:'latest'})]);
```

Now in terms of the promise not resolving, I'm assuming the event is generated from `oracle.LogResult()`.  In this case, what you'd want to do is setup your promises to listen for the event first, for example:

```
let first = getFirstEvent();
let second = getSecondEvent();
```

Now you have 2 promises that are listening for the events.  Next, you generate the event:

```
oracle.LogResult({ fromBlock: 'latest' });
oracle.LogResult({ fromBlock: 'latest' });
```

Finally, you ensure you wait on the result of the promises:

```
return await Promise.all([first, second]);
```